# Calling createEntityManager in CORBA program causes exception: org.omg.CORBA.OBJECT_NOT_EXIST

Tags: exception, jpa, entitymanager, corba

I have a CORBA client-server program that is working perfectly. The client can get a servant and call methods remotely.

I would now like to make the server interact with a database using JPA. However everything goes wrong when I add this one line to the server code:

```
emf.createEntityManager();
```

The server builds, and it registers to the orbd without error. However when I run the client which tries to connect with the server I get the following exception:

> Exception: org.omg.CORBA.OBJECT_NOT_EXIST:

Full exception and stack trace are:

> Exception: org.omg.CORBA.OBJECT_NOT_EXIST: ----------BEGIN server-side stack trace----------
>   org.omg.CORBA.OBJECT_NOT_EXIST:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 401  completed: No
>       at com.sun.corba.se.impl.logging.ActivationSystemException.errorInBadServerIdHandler(ActivationSystemException.java:239)
>       at com.sun.corba.se.impl.logging.ActivationSystemException.errorInBadServerIdHandler(ActivationSystemException.java:257)
>       at com.sun.corba.se.impl.activation.ServerManagerImpl.handle(ServerManagerImpl.java:604)
>       at com.sun.corba.se.impl.orb.ORBImpl.handleBadServerId(ORBImpl.java:1602)
>       at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.checkServerId(CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:407)
>       at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:182)
>       at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequestRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1700)
>       at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1558)
>       at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleInput(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:940)
>       at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.RequestMessage_1_2.callback(RequestMessage_1_2.java:198)
>       at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:712)
>       at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.dispatch(SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.java:471)
>       at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.doWork(SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.java:1230)
>       at com.sun.corba.se.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(ThreadPoolImpl.java:490)
>       at com.sun.corba.se.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:519)
>   Caused by: com.sun.corba.se.spi.activation.ServerNotRegistered: IDL:activation/ServerNotRegistered:1.0
>       at com.sun.corba.se.impl.activation.RepositoryImpl.getDBServerDef(RepositoryImpl.java:221)
>       at com.sun.corba.se.impl.activation.RepositoryImpl.getServer(RepositoryImpl.java:228)
>       at com.sun.corba.se.impl.activation.ServerManagerImpl.getEntry(ServerManagerImpl.java:350)
>       at com.sun.corba.se.impl.activation.ServerManagerImpl.handle(ServerManagerImpl.java:566)
>       ... 12 more

To my mind, a call to `createEntityManager` is logically completely separate from the CORBA networking functionality, so I can't see how this could possible have an impact on the client connecting to the server.

Comment: perhaps if you provide the full stack trace then someone could see where it comes from?

Comment: @BillyFrost I've edited it to include the full stack trace

Comment: i'd be more interested in what are the "12 more" ... since the root of that is the user call that starts it

Comment: @BillyFrost I'm in Netbeans and that's all that I'm shown. I don't know how to expand out the '12 more'.

Answer (score 0):

The exception was coming from my EntityManagerFactory. It had nothing to do with the networking, but because I never ran the server until a client connected, no exception occurred until that point.

The exception output was not particularly useful. I found it helpful to comment out all the networking code and just run the server as a stand-alone program from development (much more useful error messages when something goes wrong).